# Is a question about software to create models on-topic?

Tags: support

I would like to ask how to convert photos of some object to 3D model, and eventually how to treat the object before taking the photos to increase accuracy of the result (see [How to optimally make a 3D model of an object using photos?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/how-to-optimally-make-a-3d-model-of-an-object-using-photos)).

Is this ok here?

Comment: Tormod presents a great answer. To add to it, 3D Printing SE is still in Beta and therefore we are still trying to determine which questions should or shouldn't be asked on the site. So, as Tormod suggests, go ahead and ask your question and we'll close questions based on community responses. Thank you and welcome to 3D Printing SE!

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it later. I will focus on how to treat the object to improve the scan, while  the software part will be on the side, since it's more for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OlafM! One could say that 3D reconstruction is a bit sidetracked from typical 3D printing (apart from the 3D part :)), but then again, 3D reconstruction and printing also go hand in hand in some cases, such as with 3D scanners.

Since 3D reconstruction can be a fairly math heavy topic, and I am unsure as to whether you will get any good answers here (but that depends on the specific question too, of course!). I suggest you simply write the question as best you can, and give it a try here. If it doesn't get any response, try heading over to some other site as well, such as:

- Robotics SE
- Mathematics SE
- Stack Overflow
- Computer Science SE
- Electrical Engineering SE